# many-to-many find model with multiple conditions

Tags: yii2, many-to-many

I have a database in which I store shoots and also their tags. They are related with a many-to-many relationship and I use a junction table to store the relations. Know I want to implement a search in which a can specify N tags and only shoots that have those N tags should be returned. I already implemented searching for one tag, but I have no idea how to search for N tags. If possible I would like to do that the most yii way possible.

Here's the relation I use in my model:

```
/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getShootTags()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ShootTag::className(), ['shoot_id' => 'shoot_id']);
}

public function getTags()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Tags::className(), ['tag_id' => 'tag_id'])->via('shootTags');
}
```

My search model looks like this:

```
namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use app\models\Shoots;

/**
* ShootsSearch represents the model behind the search form of 
`app\models\Shoots`.
*/
class ShootsSearch extends Shoots
{
 public $tag;
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['shoot_id', 'date'], 'integer'],
        [['filename', 'tag'], 'safe'],
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function scenarios()
{
    // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
    return Model::scenarios();
}

/**
 * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
 *
 * @param array $params
 *
 * @return ActiveDataProvider
 */
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Shoots::find();

    // add conditions that should always apply here

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    // grid filtering conditions
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'shoot_id' => $this->shoot_id,
        'date' => $this->date,
    ]);
    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->tag]);
    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'filename', $this->filename]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
}
```

Comment: Do you need records with all those N tags, or one is enough?

Comment: add the `controller/action` that you are using and the view involved, it can be done easily but until all info provided which makes lesser typing in when providing solutions

Answer (score 0):

will something like this work for you?

```
Shoot::find()->joinWith('tags')->where(['tag.name' => ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']]);
```

this will join both the pivot table and the tag table with rules you have set up and filter by tag names with an `IN` statement